# Rails: What is a "true" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails is returning an error message that reads:

> showing (file path) where line #19 raised: true

If some could at least explain to me what this means, even in general, that'd be great.

On that line I'm trying to run an each loop on an array consisting of joined records (sending to a ransack search_form_for):

```
@q = Store.joins(:address, :city).ransack(params[:q])
@stores = @q.result.includes(:address, :cities, distinct: true)
```

I get this error whenever I try to work with @stores (.each, ,to_a, etc.). What does it mean?

Comment: You sure you can pass in `distinct` into `includes`? What field do you want to make distinct?

Comment: Store, but I really just want to know what the error means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `distinct: true` is not going to do what you are expecting it to.  See the documentation for `includes`:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes

With what you have written, ActiveRecord is going to try loading a relationship named `distinct` and a nested relationship named `true`.  That's why you are getting the confusing error about "true".